# Regarding Admob Integration on Android

Tags: android, admob

I m new to integrating Admob with client app which is already live on Google Play Store.

I have created a publisher ID for my account.

Now i have created a live ad unit with my account at admob (Google). Now should I link newly created add unit to the client app available in Play store , so as to receive new ads ?

Thanks

Comment: I m receiving this error when I m trying to get ads for publisher ID created by Me for my account --- There was problem getting an ad response . Error code : 0.    Failed to load ad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Android AdMob guide [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start). It should have all the information that you need for AdMob integration.

Comment: Yes @Lefteris ... I m already studying this guide and trying to implement. I will get back.   Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The best guide for adding advertising here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
After the creation of advertising, it can manifest itself immediately, but after some time. If you are worried that something is done wrong, ask for a test ad:

```
AdRequest adRequest = adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
```

Connection applications with Google Play did not give me anything. I understand it is made for:

- Beautiful icon in the console
- Bans simultaneously in Google Play and admob